# Populating dropdown list from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to populate my dropdown list on a form with data from a database, i have tried the following but to no success it gives me an error saying unexpected ; i have tried removing but still getting errors?

```
 echo form::label('myproduct', 'My Product:');
         echo form::select('form[myproduct]', $sql = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM claim_incentive"); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {echo "<option value=\"1\">" . $row['description'] . "</option>"; }
```

I think i could be putting the code in the wrong place as i have two php files, one is the controller, my code below:

```
public function action_claimincentive() {
                    $this->template->content = View::factory('crm/uk/claim_incentive_form');
                    $this->template->content->thanks = false;
                    $this->template->content->val = '';
                    $this->template->content->post = '';

                        if ($this->request->post('form')) {
                                    $post = $this->request->post('form');

                                    $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `claim_incentive_form_data` (`User Reference`, `Claimant Postcode`, `Purchase Order No.`, `Claimant Email Address`, `Storename`, `Storetown`, `Date of Sale`, `Date of Delivery`, `Acknowledgement No.`, `Product`)
                                                                        VALUES (:userreference, :claimantpostcode, :orderno, :email, :storename, :storetown, :dateofsale, :dateofdelivery, :acknowledgementno, :product)');
                                    $stmt->param(':userreference', $post['userreference']);
                                    $stmt->param(':claimantpostcode', $post['claimantpostcode']);
                                    $stmt->param(':orderno', $post['orderno']);
                                    $stmt->param(':email', $post['email']);
                                    $stmt->param(':storename', $post['storename']);
                                    $stmt->param(':storetown', $post['storetown']);
                                    $stmt->param(':dateofsale', $post['dateofsale']);
                                    $stmt->param(':dateofdelivery', $post['dateofdelivery']);
                                    $stmt->param(':acknowledgementno', $post['acknowledgementno']);
                                    $stmt->param(':product', $post['product']);
                                        try {
                                                $stmt->execute();
                                                $this->template->content->post = $post;
                                                $this->template->content->thanks = true;
                                                } catch (Exception $e) {
                                                    FB::error($e);
                                                }

                    }
                }
```

And the other is the actual form, see part of it below:

```
echo form::label('dateofdelivery', 'Date of Delivery:');
         echo form::input('form[dateofdelivery]', $val, array('class'=>'input', 'id'=>'dateofdelivery'));

         echo form::label('acknowledgementno', 'Acknowledgement No:');
         echo form::input('form[acknowledgementno]', $val, array('class'=>'input', 'id'=>'acknowledgementno'));

         echo form::label('product', 'Product:');
         echo form::select('form[product]', array(
                                            '' => 'Please select from the list',
                                            'In store' => 'In store',
                                            'Word of mouth' => 'Word of mouth',
                                            'Television' => 'Television',
                                            'Newspaper' => 'Newspaper',
                                            'Magazine' => 'Magazine',
                                            'Internet' => 'Internet',
                                            'Google Reasearch' => 'Google Reasearch',
                                            'Radio' => 'Radio',
                                            'Medical Recommendation' => 'Medical Recommendation',
                            ), '', array('class="select"', 'id'=>'product'));

        echo form::submit('btnSubmit', 'Submit', array('id'=>'btnSubmit', 'class'=>'button'));
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';

        echo form::close();
```

Comment: try var_dumping your results and make sure you actually have things to display. is the query even being executed? and use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your markup, let's see:

In this line you have some errors:

```
echo form::select('form[myproduct]', $sql = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM claim_incentive");
```

You are opening two parenthesis but only closing one should be something like:

```
echo form::select('form[myproduct]', $sql = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM claim_incentive"));
```

It's not necessary to assign the sql variable inside the method, any way I don't know which kind of framework are you using, so I am only noticing syntax errors.

Comment: I think i could be putting the code in the wrong place, i have two php files, i will update my question thanks!